# How to unistall utorrent server and libtorrent

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, alien

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 32bit.

I downloaded `utserver.tar.gz`  file today from [utorrent.com](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux) and converted it into deb file using alien by `sudo alien -d utserver.tar.gz`.
It worked well and I installed it using the terminal.

But I couldn't find the app in my app list. I tried installing it through Ubuntu Software Center and reinstalled it but it didn't work.
Then I tried libtorrent from Ubuntu Software Center and after it was installed, the same thing happened!

No sign of them either in my app list or in the "installed" option of the software center.

How can I uninstall them?

Comment: μTorrent currently gives a server, not a client. You are not supposed to download torrents, but to create and spread. If you want a client just do sudo apt-get install transmission

Comment: thanks....i've transmission pre installed bt i was searching for utorrent torrent client to enable shutting down my pc after completing all the downloads.. Can u plz tell me what to do to enable such in transmission?

Comment: i think http://ktorrent.pwsp.net has that ability of shutdown. Please remember to check the answer as correct if it worked.

Comment: Ktorrent install: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports - sudo apt-get update - sudo apt-get install ktorrent

Answer (score 0):

To remove **utserver** and **libtorrent** you can run:

> sudo dpkg -r utserver
>
> sudo apt-get remove libtorrent14

To remove **alien** run:

> sudo apt-get remove alien

Remember to do:

> sudo apt-get autoremove

in case some packages are still installed and you don't need them.